# Plot raster with continuous color palette with zero in white (R Base)

Tags: r, plot, raster, color-palette

As much as I looked at other questions I couldn't solve my problem (I'm new in R).
I simply need to plot a raster where the minimum value (let's say color red) goes to zero (white) and from zero to maximum (color blue) continuously.
I would like to create that color palette independently if the data is symmetrically distributed in negative and positive values.

Let's say I have a raster with this values:

```
library(raster)
values <- c(seq(-2000,0,by=1),seq(1,499,by=1))
values <- sample(values)

r <- raster(ncol=50,nrow=50)
r <- setValues(r,values)

plot(r)
```

If this has already been resolved in another question, I would appreciate any information.

Comment: Look at the rgb() function and the functions it’s help page references.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can use `RColorBrewer` or `colorRampPalette` to achieve this (or a combination of both) and by setting `breaks`.

```
library(raster)
library(RColorBrewer)

breakpoints <- c(-2000, seq(0, 500, 55.6))
colors <- c("red", RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9, "Blues"))
plot(r, breaks = breakpoints, col = colors)
```

Output
[image]

You can also do something similar with colorRampPalette by setting two unique colors. Then, in parenthesis, define how many colors on the gradient you want.

```
colors <- c("red", colorRampPalette(c("steelblue1", "steelblue4"))(9))
```

You can also use these both in conjunction with one another.

```
colors <- c("red", colorRampPalette(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9, "Blues"))(11))
```

If you want red also continuous, then you could create a gradient for both.

```
breakpoints <- c(seq(-2000, -1, 222), seq(0, 500, 55.6))
colors <- c(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9, "Reds"), RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9, "Blues"))
plot(r, breaks = breakpoints, col = colors)
```

Output

[image]

It's a little easier to set these using `ggplot`. You essentially need to rescale the values on a scale of 0 to 1 to make 0 the "midpoint".

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

rdf <- as.data.frame(r, xy = TRUE) 

rdf %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_raster(aes(x, y, fill = layer)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(
    colours = colorRampPalette(rev(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(11, "RdBu")))(255),
    values = c(1.0, (0 - min(rdf$layer)) / (max(rdf$layer) - min(rdf$layer)), 0)
  )
```

Output

[image]